# PC Wi-Fi network speed too slow

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-router

My laptops have 2 MebiBytes/sec transfer speed between them even though my laptops have 130 megabits/sec Wi-Fi connection link speed on a 300 megabits/sec router. Shouldn't the transfer speed be around 10 MebiBytes/sec?

Comment: It shoild indeed be faster, but this really depends on other devices and interference.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two laptops as clients of the same band of the same AP, and they are maintaining a 130 megabits/sec signaling rate in both the client-to-AP and AP-to-client direction, the effective throughput should be around 5 MebiBytes per second.

When two Wi-Fi clients talk to each other, they do not send their packets directly to each other. Instead, every packet is relayed by the AP. So every packet transits the RF channel twice, which cuts the effective bandwidth in half.

Then, TCP over IPv4 over Wi-Fi, with 802.11n frame aggregation, is only about 60% efficient (maybe up to almost 80%, but I'm using 60% to be conservative here).

So…
Wireless-to-wireless cuts bandwidth in half: 130 Mbps / 2 = 65 Mbps
Wi-Fi overhead leaves only 60%: 65 Mbps * .6 = 39 Mbps
megabits to MebiBytes conversion is about 1/8.4: 39 Mbps / 8.4 = 4.6 MebiBytes/sec

So, your throughput should be able to be about twice what you've measured. Likely explanations:

1. Perhaps you're not really averaging the 130 Mbps signaling rate (maybe you looked at the speed your clients are getting when transmitting to the AP, but not the speed your AP is getting when transmitting to your clients).
2. Perhaps the file transfer tool you're using is inefficient. It would be interesting to see what speed `iperf` gets between the two machines.